# Работа с get методом. Передача параметров

Tags: php, get

[image: Загружаю переменную после нажатия кнопки удалить,дальше проверяю ее наличие два раза число(22) то есть я нажал на кнопку удалить у поля со 2 id[![][1]]][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Код работает до момента когда я делаю запрос delete from он его просто как будто не читает. Не понимаю в чем дело.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправьте этот запрос:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($c, 'DELETE FROM arendator_ob WHERE id_ar = $id_del');
```

на этот:

```
 $sql = mysqli_query($c, 'DELETE FROM arendator_ob WHERE id_ar = '.$id_del);
```

З.Ы. соблюдайте табуляцию, пожалуйста!

З.Ы.Ы. делая такие запросы говорим привет sql-инъекциям! (вам можно приводить переменную к int типу. `(int)$id_del`)

З.Ы.Ы.Ы. расширьте проверку `if(isset($_GET['id_ob']) && !empty($_GET['id_ob']))`